# When field "IS NULL" join on an alternative field - Access 2007

Tags: sql, if-statement, ms-access-2007, left-join

So the short end of it is this is what I want to do, but I don't know the proper syntax.

Table 1, Table 2
Name, SSN, DOB, List, Date

I want to do a left join using the SSN, but when the SSN field IS NULL I want it to join on the DOB field Where the Name matches.

I can't join on name due to the file being 19k records and most of them are common names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you can do what you want with a simple `LEFT JOIN` and the correct JOIN conditions. The trick in Access is that **IT DOES NOT LIKE** left joins with too few parentheses. When in doubt, add more parentheses. You will be surprised at what it makes possible in Access.

```
SELECT
   T1.*,
   T2.*
FROM
   (Table1 AS T1
   LEFT JOIN Table2 AS T2 ON (
      (T1.SSN = T2.SSN)
      OR (
         (T1.SSN IS NULL)
         AND (T1.DOB = T2.DOB)
         AND (T1.Name = T2.Name)
      )
   ));
```

If this doesn't work, please let me know and I'll see what I can do.

Note that you may or may not be able to go to the design view of this in the GUI query editor.

Also note that since NULL does not equal NULL, you don't need additional conditions before the `OR` about `X.SSN IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: With some tweaking I managed to get this to work. I was using a ton of parenthesis, but I see now that my syntax was wrong... as per usual. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Would you mind sharing what about my query was not correct, either by editing the post or by describing it or by pointing me to another place online where I can see?

Comment: Well, to be honest what I wanted to do was much more complicated than what I asked; it was just that basic syntax that I was getting wrong--which you clarified.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps:

```
SELECT  *
FROM Table7
INNER JOIN Table8
ON Table7.SSN = Table8.SSN
WHERE Table8.SSN Is Not Null
UNION
SELECT  *
FROM Table7
INNER JOIN Table8
ON Table7.DOB = Table8.DOB
WHERE Table8.SSN Is Null
```

Note that the result will not be editable.

Comment: Apparently I was making it harder than it was. I was doing all sorts of nesting and such. I'll give this a try and see if it works.

Comment: I did try this and for what ever reason it wasn't working for a LEFT JOIN. I gave the me appropriate product without the extra rows from the first table that I need.

Comment: The point was a union of two inner joins, a left join was not needed.

Comment: I realized that after the point. lol. I had to create a third union selecting the rows with all null values in the ssn and dob fields before I could get all the records returned.

Answer (score 1):

break it up into 2 queries

/*1st query*/
SELECT

LEFT JOIN
...
...WHERE Table2.SSN is NOT NULL

UNION
/* 2nd query */
SELECT
.....
FROM TABLE1 t1,
TABLE2 t2
WHERE t2.SSN is NULL